# Corona - How to update list pictures when scrolling?

Tags: scroll, tableview, coronasdk

I have a table view(list) whose rows includes pictures and text.
I have more than thousand pictures, I dont want to keep all in app file.

I can get text by web services but I don't know how to get pictures by web service?
I saw some apps whichupdates default pictures in list when scrolling the list?

How can I do it ?

[image: like png below, updates pictures on visible part of list during scrolling]

M.

Comment: You can use the [loadRemoteImage](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/loadRemoteImage.html).

Comment: do you want them to load initially or only when the user is scrolling to that row?

Comment: I want load pics only when user is scrolling rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and use it like below. Change the temp to document.directory if you want them to be there after first download:

```
local function networkListener2( event )
  myImage = display.newImageRect( "helloCopy.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, 540, 720 )
  myImage.x = display.contentCenterX
   myImage.y = display.contentCenterY
end
network.download( picUrl,"GET", networkListener2, "helloCopy.png", system.TemporaryDirectory )
```